# $P(A \cap B \subseteq C \subseteq A \cup B)$ for $3$ Bernoulli subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$

Tags: probability, set-theory

Given a set $S$ of $n$ elements.

Three subsets $A$, $B$, and $C$ are randomly and independently selected from it. Each random subset is formed as follows: each element of the set $S$ is included in the subset independently of the others with probability $p$, and not included with probability $1 − p$. (This process
is repeated for each subset.)

Find the probability of the event $D = \{A \cap B \subseteq C \subseteq A \cup B\}$.

I tried to do it through addition of sets. I wanted to start by trying to identify a lot of elementary outcomes in this task, but I didn’t know how to approach. I would be glad to know the solutions, or at least essential hints.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The event $D$ is of the form $\forall x \in S: D_x$, with
$$D_x := ((x \in A \cap B \implies x \in C) \text{ and } (x \in C \implies x \in A \cup B)).$$
The family $\{D_x\}$ is mutually independent (why?) so $\mathbb{P}(D) = \prod_{x \in S} \mathbb{P}(D_x)$. It should be straightforward to find $\mathbb{P}(D_x^c)$ in terms of $p$.